# Path to an embedded object

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Given a nested array or hash as the receiver and some object as the argument, what is the best way to return the path to an occurrence of the object if the receiver includes the object, or `nil` otherwise? I define *path* as an array of array indices or hash keys that leads to the object. The argument object will never be any of the hash keys, and will never appear more than once. For example, I expect:

```
[
  :a,
  [:b, :c, {:d => :foo}],
  :e,
]
.path_to(:foo) # => [1, 2, :d]

{
  :a => [3, "foo"],
  :b => 5,
  :c => 2,
}
.path_to(3) # => [:a, 0]
```

When there is no occurrence, return `nil`:

```
[:foo, "hello", 3]
.path_to(:bar) => nil
```

If no one comes up with a reasonable answer, then I will post my own answer shortly.

Comment: @toro2k I haven't written it down much.

Comment: The return value *must* be an array? for example wouldn't `:c` be enough? it must be `[:c]`?

Comment: @sawa Nice question.. I have confusion. will it be `[:a, 0]` or `[:a, 1]` in the second example?

Comment: [:a, 0], since you are looking for the 3, not the "foo"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing like a bit of recursion.

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class Array
  def path_to(obj)
    # optimize this
    Hash[self.each.with_index.to_a.map {|k,v| [v,k]}].path_to(obj)
  end
end

class Hash
  def path_to(obj)
    inverted = self.invert
    if inverted[obj]
      [inverted[obj]]
    else
      self.map {|k, v|
        if v.respond_to?(:path_to)
          if res = v.path_to(obj)
            [k] + res
          end
        end
      }.find {|path|
        path and path[-1] != nil
      }
    end
  end
end

describe "path_to" do
  it "should work with really simple arrays" do
    [:a, :e,].path_to(:a).must_equal [0]
  end
  it "should work with simple arrays" do
    [:a, [:b, :c], :e,].path_to(:c).must_equal [1, 1]
  end
  it "should work with arrays" do
    [:a, [:b, :c, {:d => :foo}], :e,].path_to(:foo).must_equal [1, 2, :d]
  end
  it "should work with simple hashes" do
    {:d => :foo}.path_to(:foo).must_equal [:d]
  end
  it "should work with hashes" do
    ({:a => [3, "foo"], :b => 5, :c => 2,}.path_to(3).must_equal [:a, 0])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I was wondering which to chose among yours and Rafa's answer. Rafa's turned out to be about three times faster. Both answers are good. Thanks.

Comment: His solution is better in terms of module encapsulation too, IIRC ruby people don't like messing with core objects, which is a shame.

Comment: This turned out to raise an error for `{:b => [5], :a => [3]}.path_to(3)`.

Comment: Added another `nil`-guard.

Answer (score 4):

Here you are my own recursive solution. I am sure that it could be improved but it is a good start and works exactly as requested.

```
# path.rb
module Patheable
  def path_to item_to_find
    path = []
    find_path(self, item_to_find, path)
    result = path.empty? ? nil : path
    result.tap { |r| puts r.inspect } # just for testing
  end

  private 

  def find_path(current_item, item_to_find, result)
    if current_item.is_a?(Array)
      current_item.each_with_index do |value, index| 
        find_path(value, item_to_find, result.push(index))
      end
    elsif current_item.is_a?(Hash)
      current_item.each do |key, value| 
        find_path(value, item_to_find, result.push(key))
      end
    else
      result.pop unless current_item == item_to_find
    end
  end
end

class Array
  include Patheable
end

class Hash
  include Patheable
end

[
  :a,
  [:b, :c, {:d => :foo}],
  :e,
].path_to(:foo) # => [1, 2, :d]

{
  :a => [3, "foo"],
  :b => 5,
  :c => 2,
}.path_to(3) # => [:a, 0]

[:foo, "hello", 3].path_to(:bar)  # => nil
#end path.rb

# example of use
$ ruby path.rb
[1, 2, :d]
[:a, 0]
nil
```

Comment: This seems to run pretty fast. The use of module is impressive.

Comment: Sorry. This turned out to return wrong result for `{:b => [5], :a => [3]}.path_to(3)`. Expected is `[:a, 0]`, but it returns `[:b, :a, 0]`.

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer that I came up with.

```
class Object
  def path_to obj; end
end

class Array
  def path_to obj
    if i = index(obj) then return [i] end
    a = nil
    _, i = to_enum.with_index.find{|e, _| a = e.path_to(obj)}
    a.unshift(i) if i
  end
end

class Hash
  def path_to obj
    if value?(obj) then return [key(obj)] end
    a = nil
    kv = find{|_, e| a = e.path_to(obj)}
    a.unshift(kv.first) if kv
  end
end
```